# domain roots to html folder - website content is located on other folder - how to display?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, dns, symlink

My domain www.example.com roots to the html folder of my webspace.
This is located here:

> /var/www/virtual/myaccount/html

But my website content is located there:

> /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public/index.php

How is it possible that I can display my site if I call my domain?
Do I need here a htaccess file in my html folder? Or is it possible with a symlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it depends on which webserver you use, its configuration but in many cases following symlinks is enabled, so give it a try with:

```
ln -s /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public /var/www/virtual/myaccount/html
```

Comment: yeah, thanks. this push me into the right direction. Your answer works, if there is index.php after public/. thanks!
`ln -s /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public/index.php /var/www/virtual/myaccount/html`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Change Document Root:**
 You domain DocumentRoot would be set to /var/www/virtual/myaccount/html , hence it root to this folder. 

 Solution is to make /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public/ as DocumentRoot for domain www.example.com and enable Indexes option for this directory. This setting can be done in httpd.conf file. 

 Example stanza is given below.

```
<VirtualHost www.exampl.com>
DocumentRoot /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public/
ErrorLog logs/www.exampl.com-error_log
CustomLog logs/www.exampl.com-access_log common
<Directory /var/www/virtual/myaccount/app/current/public/>
Options Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Use Symlinks**
Symlinks also can be used but this should be enabled for current DocumentRoot Directory.